# Average growth rate estimation

Tags: econometrics, economic-growth

How can we estimate the average growth rate from 2011 to 2022,when with time, the quantity is first increasing at decreasing rate, then decreasing and then again increasing at an increasing rate with a rapid decline in 2022? For reference, I have attached the scatter plot! I would be grateful if you could suggest some regression models that I can run to get the average growth rate.

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: This looks too erratic for any other model than a constant + noise.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Are you suggesting to use white noise model? If so how?